# Cosmos DB request errors after migration

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I made data migration with help of the Azure Database Migration Service from Mongo3.4 to Azure Cosmos DB. All collections were copied. Then I deployed app and run report inside the application. I was receiving errors in k8s like:

```
[report-srv-8a49370c7976028acfc037b7b9b69a37b34b8afezmg5r] 2020-09-17T14:12:27.653Z ERROR: [handleControllerHeart] Error handling heart:  {"err":{"driver":true,"name":"MongoError","index":0,"code":16500}}
```

> Error=16500, RetryAfterMs=5481, Details='Response status code does not
> indicate success: TooManyRequests (429); Substatus: 3200; ActivityId:
> ********; Reason: ({\r\n  "Errors": [\r\n    "Request rate is large. More Request Units may be needed, so no changes were made.
> Please retry this request later. Learn more:
> http://aka.ms/cosmosdb-error-429

Then I increased RUs but the same behavior.

Does anybody have experience with migration from Mongo3.4 to Azure Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase Throughput aka RUs (Request Units). You can do it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-database-throughput?tabs=dotnetv2), see how much you are using already from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db) and may be double it then from the dashboard as before see how much you used when you ran your report and then adjust with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As a result we created indexes in each collection and that gave us a possibility to decrease shared RU.
Increasing RU also helped but queries were very slow.